# WebApi Architecture query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, architecture, asp.net-web-api, restful-architecture

I am designing architecture of my Project, which would have

1. Web Application (Client)
2. Windows Application (Client)
3. Mobile Application (Client)
4. Service Layer (would be done using Web Api)
5. Business Logic Layer
6. Data Access Layer
7. Data Object Layer

My question is do i need to create two different MVC projects for Web Application and Service Layer (Web Api). As both for them would be hosted. I have seen that WebApi template also supports ActionMethods (when class is inherited by Controller class). So can Web Api template be used as WebApp as well as Service Layer.

What is the best practice that is followed.

I know there similar questions on these locations

[What is the correct architecture for MVC4 WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653673/what-is-the-correct-architecture-for-mvc4-webapi)

[Using ASP.NET WebApi with a 3 Tier Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180577/using-asp-net-webapi-with-a-3-tier-architecture)

But i wanted to be specific with my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to create two separate applications? The web app and the API serve two completely distinct purposes. You can still host them together.

Comment: The simple approach is you can separate Web APi in standalone assembly and do reference it into your web project. But consider using MVC on client side instead of MVC on Service side, This way you don't need to use ASP.NET MVC anymore. You can use Angularjs or Durandal.js to manage on the client side, just only Web APi on Server side is enough for you

Comment: @AntP, The Question for creating two separate project (for WebApi and WebApp) arised before me, as MVC WebAPI template also support functionality that MVC Internet Applicaiton template supports. Hence if both the apps would be hosted, then do i need to create two different projects and host it as two different Websites in IIS. What would be the purpose of making two different projects, and if not made (only single project is made for WebApi and WebApp) what all issues can it create. Can u help me on this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only practical difference I can see is that if you put them in the same project, your API is suddenly tightly coupled to your web app and can never live without it, which is unnecessary.

Create separate projects in the same solution and host them as two separate sites.

Comment: ok. thankz everyone.
if the webapp is down in IIS then my service will also get down (If i used a single project). hence making two separate project is a good approach. Even if webapp is down for maintainance, then also webapi service would be running and serving my other clients.

Answer (score 1):

Defining the architecture requires establishing responsibility of each component.
ASP.NET Web API must usually be a light layer concerned with the presentation of the state in pure HTTP semantics - kinda similar to what SOAP does in a traditional web service.

As such, in an ASP.NET Web API application you should have really very little business logic. So I would not simply add overhead of an additional **physical layer** which includes network latency, serialization and deserialization, etc.

This is my preferred approach:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am sorry but i didnt understand ur architecture. Do you mean MVC WebApp would call MVC WebAPI which would call BLL and DAL.
Is it like this.
MVC Web App -> MVC WebAPI -> BLL -> DAL




DAL -> BLL -> MVC WebAPI -> MVC Web App -> RETURNS VIEW.

Comment: @shakti I mean ASP.NET MVC calls BL. There should be little reason to go to Web API.

Comment: I have multiple clients which would be calling the server for the functionality. The functionality on the server should be a common API and should give result to all my clients (web, mobile, windows). Hence the call from MVC Web App should go to Web Api, call from mobile should go to Web Api, call from windows should go to Web Api. And from Web API the call would go forward to BLL and DAL. Please let me know if iam wrong with my architecture.

Comment: @shakti well that is my advice. As I explained, Web API is a thin shell around your internal API which should be implemented as a library and this is what MVC will be using. I dont think I can explain  any clearer. But if you would like to take another approach, your welcome.